# How to cross verify/check storage of initialized and uninitialized variables in c on Linux platform

Tags: c

We know that initialized global, extern, static (both local and global) and constant global variables are stored in initialized data memory segment block of memory layout and that uninitialized global, extern, static (both local and global) and constant global variables are stored in BSS block of memory segment.

I want to cross verify this on linux platform.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Did you try `objdump` and the cross reference that the linker generates when asked?

Comment: actually i want to verify total memory consumed by the program, DS block and BSS block